# Inserting new Firestore document at the beginning of an ArrayList using SnapshotListener flips the order of the query onCreate

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to use Firestore to query and update a list of chat messages, which will show a fixed number (5 for this example) of the most recent queried messages at the bottom, descending upward by timestamp, and messages added after the query in the same order below those, like a typical chat app:

- queriedmessage1<-oldest queried
- queriedmessage2
- queriedmessage3
- queriedmessage4
- queriedmessage5<-newest queried
- newmessage1<-added after query

This requires me to sort the query descending and use setReverseLayout on the RecyclerView's LayoutManager. I am then required to add new messages to the beginning of the `ArrayList` to ensure they appear at the bottom, as position [0] is now at the bottom of the screen. Here is my code to do that:

```
Query query = mCollection.orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(5);



 query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                switch (documentChange.getType()) {
                    case ADDED:
                        Message message = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Message.class);


                        mMessages.add(0,message);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        }
```

However, changing  `messages.add(message)` to `messages.add(0,message)` changes the order the messages are displayed onCreate, leaving me with something like this:

- queriedmessage5<-newest queried
- queriedmessage4
- queriedmessage3
- queriedmessage2
- queriedmessage1<-oldest queried
- newmessage1<-added by user after query

How do I make a distinction between the messages added onCreate and those added after to create my desired effect?